# how to delete every char except newline?

Tags: line-breaks

Is there a simple way to delete all text except newlines ?

I found one that removes all empty lines `:g/^$/d`.

but I am looking at the opposite functionality, some command that deletes everything except newlines ?

If you are wondering why, it's mainly because once you delete everything, you have to again press `i` and `<Enter>` a couple of times to recreate the space you are working with.

Comment: Would `:%s/.*//` do?

Comment: yes thank you :)

I am new to vim, and tried chatGPT a few times before actually asking here.

Comment: Don't ask ChatGPT, read Vim's built in `:help`.

Answer (score 3):

To remove all content of a line, you can use the `:substitute` command (see `:help substitute`) like this:

```
:s/.*//
```

It will substitute any character (`.`), repeated 0 or more times (`*`) with nothing. It will preserve line endings.

You can prepend `:substitute` with a range, e.g. the whole buffer (`%`) or a visual selection.

As an alternative to get several empty lines, you can prefix `i` or `o` with a *count*. Both `23i<CR><Esc>` or `23o<Esc>` will create 23 empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you want to do it, but here we go:

```
:%norm! D
```

This keeps the newlines, but makes every line empty.

Or if you want to delete the whole buffer completely, including the line breaks:

```
:%d
```

Or if you want to only delete non-empty lines (you can use other patterns like all lines starting with a `#`, so commented lines: `^#`):

```
:g/./d
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `:v`, as in `:v/^$/d`, since OP had a command that almost worked but wanted to, well, invert the pattern